# Why should i use transport protocol(mpeg-ts) to send h264 format over network?

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I am aware there is already a NAL unit which separates frames in h264.  If I use a reliable TCP connection, why do I need mpeg-ts format to send data over a network?

I have tried it by using gstreamer. But the case which use mpeg-ts only works. tcpsrc and tcpsink just sends all data over the network. It seems that there are no differences between using TCP and just reading file in locally.

with mpeg-ts

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc horizontal-speed=5 ! x264enc tune="zerolatency" threads=1 ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink host=192.168.0.211 port=8554
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=8554 host=192.168.0.211 ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

without mpeg-ts

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc horizontal-speed=5 ! x264enc tune="zerolatency" threads=1 !  tcpserversink host=192.168.0.211 port=8554
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=8554 host=192.168.0.211 ! h264parse ! "video/x-h264, format=byte-stream" ! avdec_h264 ! ximagesink
```

Answer (score 1):

The container is mostly needed for timing information. Timing information is crucial for many applications, such as synced audio. Or, if you are using a variable frame rate, or frames are dropped, the video may play faster or slower than intended. If you don't need those features, and will not need them in the future, then you may not need the overhead.